# WriteableBitmap adding black padding to right

Tags: silverlight, canvas, bitmap, silverlight-3.0, actualwidth

I'm trying to make an `Image` out of one of my `Canvas` (`myPrintingCanvas`). But the Width of the image is getting atleast twice wider than the Canvas, and the extra space that is created is back. If I try on another `Canavas` (`LayoutRoot`), it works as intended.

My observation is that on `myPrintingCanvas` the ActualWidth is always 0. `LayoutRoot` has a correct `ActualWidth`. Not sure if it has anything to do with the extra padding, and I have failed on getting the `ActualWidth` for `myPrintingCanvas` (using `UpdateLayout` and `Measure`).

Code:

```
//Code to render the content of myPrintingCanvas
...

//Make the WriteableBitmap 
WriteableBitmap myWriteableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(myPrintingCanvas, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Creating the `WriteableBitmap` with a fixed size and then calling its `Render` method to render the bitmap?  `Canvas` has some weird behaviors because it [is an anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/21/why-i-don-t-like-canvas.aspx) in Silverlight and WPF and breaks many rules about layout. The code for creating a fixed size `WriteableBitmap` and rendering to it would look something like this:

```
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
        bmp.Render(myPrintingCanvas, null);
        bmp.Invalidate();
```

One advantage of this technique is that if you need to grab multiple images you can reuse the same `WriteableBitmap` instead of recreating it every time.